# Python overflowerror

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and I am getting the following error. How can I fix it?

```
for y in range(1, x/2):
```

OverflowError: range() result has too many items

CODE:

```
# Largest Prime Factor
prime = True
x = 600851475143
pNum = 0
for y in range(2, x/2):
    if (x % y == 0): # Found a factor
        for z in range(2, y/2): # Checking factor for prime
            if (y % z == 0): #
                prime = False
                break
        if (prime == True):
            pNum = y
        prime = True
print pNum
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.x, [`range(1, n)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) create a list of *n-1* items.

Use [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) unless you really need all that items at once.

**UPDATE**

According to `xrange` documentation:

> **CPython implementation detail**: `xrange()` is intended to be simple and
>   fast. Implementations may impose restrictions to achieve this. The C
>   implementation of Python restricts all arguments to native C longs
>   (“short” Python integers), and also requires that the number of
>   elements fit in a native C long. If a larger range is needed, an
>   alternate version can be crafted using the itertools module:
>   `islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1+2*(step<0))//step)`.

Complete example that use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import islice, count

prime = True
x = 600851475143
pNum = 0
for y in islice(count(2), x/2-2):
    if (x % y == 0): # Found a factor
        for z in islice(count(2), y/2-2): # Checking factor for prime
            if (y % z == 0): #
                prime = False
                break
        if (prime == True):
            pNum = y
        prime = True
print pNum
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error. for y in xrange(2, x/2):
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Answer (score 0):

Try xrange in stead of range.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange

Comment: I tried this but get the following error.     for y in xrange(2, x/2):
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.x `range()` returns a list, which is limited in capacity (by both available memory and max `long` 2^64 -1 for 64-bit Py) and thus likely to produce `OverflowError` with large datasets.

So, the prescribed solution is to use `xrange()` which returns a generator which doesn't have a fixed capacity or bound by `int` or `long` numbers for indexing.

Comment: `range` in Python 2.x returns a list, not an iterator.

Comment: D'oh! that's what I meant. Sheesh. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this but get the following error.                            for y in xrange(2, x/2):
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: @user3139886 are you using a 32-bit version of python?

Comment: How do you determine what version it is?

Comment: @user3139886 run `python -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'` if it returns True it's a 64-bit install.